# Reusing JQuery for Multiple HTML Elements

Tags: jquery, race-condition

newer dev here.

I have on a page multiple elements generated by the same JQuery. Each element loads with the proper content associated with it, but any functions — clicks on different tracks in this case — pull content from the last set.

My research thus far leads me to believe this is a case of Race Conditions.

Here's a codepen — click on any of the song titles on the left two players to see how images, song titles, artist names, and .mp3 data are pulled from #player-3.

```
$("#player-2").jAudio({
    playlist: [{
            file: "http://spindrop.io/audio/forgetme.mp3",
            thumb: "http://spindrop.io/images/ar.jpg",
            trackName: "Hungry",
            trackArtist: "American Royalty",
            trackAlbum: "Prismatic EP",
    }, {
            file: "http://spindrop.io/audio/mistakes.mp3",
            thumb: "http://spindrop.io/images/ar.jpg",
            trackName: "Red",
            trackArtist: "American Royalty",
            trackAlbum: "Prismatic EP",
    }, {
            file: "http://spindrop.io/audio/riverbed.mp3",
            thumb: "http://spindrop.io/images/ar.jpg",
            trackName: "Lifeline",
            trackArtist: "American Royalty",
            trackAlbum: "Prismatic EP",
    }]
});
$("#player-3").jAudio({
    playlist: [{
            file: "../audio/staticheart.mp3",
            thumb: "../images/geo.jpg",
            trackName: "Family",
            trackArtist: "Geographer",
            trackAlbum: "Animal Shapes",
    }, {
            file: "../audio/taillights.mp3",
            thumb: "../images/geo.jpg",
            trackName: "Looping",
            trackArtist: "Geographer",
            trackAlbum: "Animal Shapes",
    }, {
            file: "../audio/theline.mp3",
            thumb: "../images/geo.jpg",
            trackName: "Sonic",
            trackArtist: "Geographer",
            trackAlbum: "Animal Shapes",
    }]
});
```

http://codepen.io/kylebillings/pen/BKmZJx

& here's a link to a non-minified version of the jquery: https://gist.github.com/hisasann/337283

Thanks so much in advance. I'm thankful to learn a thing or two.

Comment: Do you have the link to the audio plugin you use ?

Comment: @Derlin I've made an edit above. Here's the clearest version of the script I've come across. https://gist.github.com/hisasann/337283

Comment: Ok, but did you modify it ? Where does the minified version come from ?

Comment: I would like to help, but I would need the non-min version of the script in codepen (with the playlist handling etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out your error (even if a minified version is not the best way to go when you ask someone else to debug your code).

The error is on the line:

```
this.settings = t.extend(!0, r, a)
```

`a` contains the supplied `Playlist`, while `r` contains the default arguments. I am not sure why, but if your log the `settings` variable after this line, you see that all settings objects have the same playlist.

Possible fixes:

1. swap `a` and `r`:

   ```
   this.settings = t.extend(!0, a, r)
   ```

   From the jQuery doc:

   > The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object.
2. use `{}` instead of `!0` (i.e. false)
   For this one, I am still trying to understand. It has to do with the `recursive` merge I guess, and the fact that in the console it returns a function instead of an object. Will edit as soon as I found out.

Comment: Thanks endlessly for your help despite the frustrating code. I found the minified file without any reference to documentation or even a non-minified version. 

My etiquette will improve with this. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to  upvote the answer and mark the question as answered. Happy coding!